# MS Word 2016 Mac: Multi-level List Headings won't retain settings

Tags: microsoft-word

This problem is driving me insane.

I am creating a nice template that I can reuse for design specifications. I will set up multi-level headings in the template and start to create documents form the template, but invariably the numbering breaks and it is impossible for me to fix it. Let me explain.

I will create my multi-level headings and then start to write. Everything looks correct (see below):

[image]

My 3rd level is working fine.

But after some period of time invariably I end up with this:

[image]

My third level heading is all jacked up. I set up these styles and about 2 hours into using them they were hosed.

I took screen shots of the settings, and as far as I can see **nothing changed in the settings**. What's more it doesn't appear that a setting is incorrect (see below).

[image]

I have googled the heck out of this with no luck. It seems to me that this may be a bug in Word.

Doe anyone have a solution to this issue?

Thanks,

Bryan

Comment: Word is notoriously bad at dealing with this. THere is no great solution. Often, I end up either manually typing in the section and subsection numbers manually, or creating entirely independent numbered lists (neither of which are optimal solutions). Another option is to use software that can handle things like that properly (ex.: Framemaker) - often not possible, I know

Comment: I was afraid if this. Amazing, simply amazing. How has this not been addressed. Well I guess I am going to ditch  multi-level headings. Thank you for responding. I have sunk about 20 hours into this already, I will not sink anymore wasted time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IS that first sub-sub topic really third-level?  Any chance you hit tab a time or two or three and demoted it to the point that this is actually the defined style?

I consider myself a complicated Word power user, mostly with 2003, now a couple weeks with 2016, and I haven't seen the kind of numbering screw-up you're showing here.

My suspicion is that Word has enough features--perhaps poorly documented or poorly thought-out--that it's doing the "right thing" as far as it knows.  This is a better situation than a mere bug because if you identify what put it into this state (e.g., a few extra tabs?) you can avoid doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably correct. I recently resisted this issue. I started with the blank document and very careful made changes to the multi-level headings, and then saved my document as a macro-enabled template.

Multi-level headings work, you just have to be pretty careful with them.